# Sort elements of Java ArrayList

Tags: java

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:121)
at day3.collections.SortArrayList.SortArrayList.main(SortArrayList.java:20)
```

---

```
package day3.collections.arraylist;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayListMain {

private ArrayList a;

public void demo(){

    try{

        System.out.println("enter the no to add in the array list");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int digitno = in.nextInt();
        int numbers[] = new int[digitno];

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers...");
        ArrayList arrayList1 = new ArrayList();



    for(
            int j=0;j<digitno;j++){
            numbers[j]=sc.nextInt();
            arrayList1.add(numbers[j]);
            setA(arrayList1);
        }

   }
    catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("Error:  Entered number is not found");
    }

   catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("Error:  Please enter integer values only");

   }

}

public ArrayList getA() {
    return a;
}

public void setA(ArrayList a) {
    this.a = a;
}

}



package day3.collections.SortArrayList;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;

import day3.collections.arraylist.ArrayListMain;

public class SortArrayList extends ArrayListMain {

 public static void main(String[] args) {


  ArrayListMain arrayList=new ArrayListMain();
    ArrayList arrayL=new ArrayList();
    arrayList.demo();
    arrayL.add(arrayList.getA());


Collections.sort(arrayL);


System.out.println("ArrayList elements after sorting in ascending order : ");
for(int i=0; i<arrayL.size(); i++)
  System.out.println(arrayL.get(i));

}
}
```

Comment: ArrayList is collections, why you need to sort ArrayList?

Comment: Did you know that the arraylist you're trying to sort, contains another arraylist in it?

Comment: How are the `ArrayList`s inside the `ArrayListMain` going to be compared? `ArrayLists` are not naturally comparable. You should add the parameter brackets so you can see what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arrayL.add(arrayList.getA());` should be `arrayL.addAll(arrayList.getA());`

Change your code like below

```
ArrayListMain arrayList=new ArrayListMain();
ArrayList arrayL=new ArrayList();
arrayList.demo();
arrayL.addAll(arrayList.getA()); 
          ^___here is the change
```

ArrayList  not implemented the Comparable interface.

```
public class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E>
        implements List<E>, RandomAccess, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable{

}
```

Collections.sort(); will sort based on the compareTo method of Comparable intefface.

```
public interface Comparable<T> {

   public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

See the String class syntax and it implemented the Comparable interface.

```
public final class String
    implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
{
      public int compareTo(String anotherString) {
      }
}
```

`arrayL.add(arrayList.getA());`  is equal to

```
ArrayList<String> a= new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("A");
a.add("B");
a.add("C");
a.add("D");
arrayL.add(a);
```

arrayL contains one arrayList object and its not implemented the Comparable interface so it could not sort(adding arrayList itself to arrayL).

`arrayL.addAll(arrayList.getA());`  is equal to

```
ArrayList<String> a= new ArrayList<String>();
a.add("A");
a.add("B");
a.add("C");
a.add("D");
arrayL.addAll(a);
```

arrayL contains one 4 String Objects and its implemented the Comparable interface so it able to sort(adding arrayList values to arrayL ).

Comment: can i know the diff why this error comes...

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the arraL a List and add all elements of your arrayList. So:

```
List<WhateverTypeYouNeed> arrayL = new ArrayList<WhateverTypeYouNeed>();
arrayL.addAll(arrayList.getA());
Collections.sort(arrayL);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting an instance of `ArrayList` into another `ArrayList` and then sort the latter. Sorting this way requires all elements to be `Comparable`, but as an `ArrayList` is not `Comparable`, your code fails.

It think the problem is in line:

```
arrayL.add(arrayList.getA());
```

It probably should be:

```
arrayL.addAll(arrayList.getA());
```

Btw.: Horrible formatting and naming! Consider redesign!

Answer (score 0):

For the fact that ArrayList does not implement Comparable you will have to use the sort()-method that takes a Comparator-object as parameter, and implement a compare-method yourself:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)